# Converting an element of list of list to a row of data

Tags: python

I am trying to split a list into a row of data, such that all elements are ',' separated. I am using the following commands, with fin_new being a list of lists -

```
element=fin_new[i]
element=str(element)
element_list = ','.join([str(v) for v in element])
sys.stdout.write(element_list + '\n')
```

But the output from this gives all the elements seperated by tab. For ex -

```
Input : [11581,115821138]
Output : [,',1,1,5,8,1,',,, ,',1,1,5,8,1,1,1,3,8,',]
```

What i want is -

```
11581 , 115811138
```

Comment: Don't do `element=str(element)`

Comment: Woah! worked... thanks a ton... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in comments:

```
Don't do element=str(element) – Barmar
```